# Neo4j Enterprise Server 2.0.0M02 Fails to start

Tags: neo4j

I just downloaded neo4j enterprise a few backs ago and had it set it up successfully to run on the cloud (EC2). It stored about 50 nodes in a span of 3 days, was just doing simple testing and playing with the database commands.

Today it suddenly terminated itself and 'failed to start'. On inspecting, message.log shows this:

```
/usr/local/neo4j-enterprise-2.0.0/data/graph.db/neostore.relationshiptypestore.db.names non clean shutdown detected
2013-05-04 05:39:29.957+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.n.s.StoreFactory]: [/usr/local/neo4j-enterprise-2.0.0/data/graph.db/neostore.relationshiptypestore.db.names] brickCount=0 brickSize=0b mappedMem=0b (storeSize=38b)
2013-05-04 05:39:29.959+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.n.s.StoreFactory]: /usr/local/neo4j-enterprise-2.0.0/data/graph.db/neostore.relationshiptypestore.db non clean shutdown detected
2013-05-04 05:39:29.960+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.n.s.StoreFactory]: [/usr/local/neo4j-enterprise-2.0.0/data/graph.db/neostore.relationshiptypestore.db] brickCount=0 brickSize=0b mappedMem=0b (storeSize=0b)
2013-05-04 05:39:29.960+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.n.s.StoreFactory]: /usr/local/neo4j-enterprise-2.0.0/data/graph.db/neostore.propertystore.db.strings non clean shutdown detected
2013-05-04 05:39:29.960+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.n.s.StoreFactory]: [/usr/local/neo4j-enterprise-2.0.0/data/graph.db/neostore.propertystore.db.strings] brickCount=3 brickSize=28288b mappedMem=28311552b (storeSize=84864b)
2013-05-04 05:39:29.961+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.n.s.StoreFactory]: /usr/local/neo4j-enterprise-2.0.0/data/graph.db/neostore.propertystore.db.index.keys non clean shutdown detected
2013-05-04 05:39:29.961+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.n.s.StoreFactory]: [/usr/local/neo4j-enterprise-2.0.0/data/graph.db/neostore.propertystore.db.index.keys] brickCount=0 brickSize=0b mappedMem=0b (storeSize=874b)
2013-05-04 05:39:29.962+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.n.s.StoreFactory]: /usr/local/neo4j-enterprise-2.0.0/data/graph.db/neostore.propertystore.db.index non clean shutdown detected
2013-05-04 05:39:29.962+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.n.s.StoreFactory]: [/usr/local/neo4j-enterprise-2.0.0/data/graph.db/neostore.propertystore.db.index] brickCount=0 brickSize=0b mappedMem=0b (storeSize=198b)
2013-05-04 05:39:29.963+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.n.s.StoreFactory]: /usr/local/neo4j-enterprise-2.0.0/data/graph.db/neostore.propertystore.db.arrays non clean shutdown detected
2013-05-04 05:39:29.963+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.n.s.StoreFactory]: [/usr/local/neo4j-enterprise-2.0.0/data/graph.db/neostore.propertystore.db.arrays] brickCount=1 brickSize=32384b mappedMem=32505856b (storeSize=32384b)
2013-05-04 05:39:29.972+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.n.s.StoreFactory]: /usr/local/neo4j-enterprise-2.0.0/data/graph.db/neostore.propertystore.db non clean shutdown detected
2013-05-04 05:39:29.972+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.n.s.StoreFactory]: [/usr/local/neo4j-enterprise-2.0.0/data/graph.db/neostore.propertystore.db] brickCount=12 brickSize=33538b mappedMem=33554432b (storeSize=402456b)
2013-05-04 05:39:29.978+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.n.s.StoreFactory]: /usr/local/neo4j-enterprise-2.0.0/data/graph.db/neostore.relationshipstore.db non clean shutdown detected
2013-05-04 05:39:29.978+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.n.s.StoreFactory]: [/usr/local/neo4j-enterprise-2.0.0/data/graph.db/neostore.relationshipstore.db] brickCount=0 brickSize=40887b mappedMem=40894464b (storeSize=33b)
2013-05-04 05:39:29.978+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.n.s.StoreFactory]: /usr/local/neo4j-enterprise-2.0.0/data/graph.db/neostore.nodestore.db.labels non clean shutdown detected
2013-05-04 05:39:29.978+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.n.s.StoreFactory]: [/usr/local/neo4j-enterprise-2.0.0/data/graph.db/neostore.nodestore.db.labels] brickCount=0 brickSize=0b mappedMem=0b (storeSize=68b)
2013-05-04 05:39:29.980+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.n.s.StoreFactory]: /usr/local/neo4j-enterprise-2.0.0/data/graph.db/neostore.nodestore.db non clean shutdown detected
2013-05-04 05:39:29.980+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.n.s.StoreFactory]: [/usr/local/neo4j-enterprise-2.0.0/data/graph.db/neostore.nodestore.db] brickCount=3 brickSize=8386b mappedMem=8388608b (storeSize=25158b)
2013-05-04 05:39:29.981+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.n.s.StoreFactory]: /usr/local/neo4j-enterprise-2.0.0/data/graph.db/neostore.schemastore.db non clean shutdown detected
2013-05-04 05:39:29.981+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.n.s.StoreFactory]: [/usr/local/neo4j-enterprise-2.0.0/data/graph.db/neostore.schemastore.db] brickCount=0 brickSize=0b mappedMem=0b (storeSize=64b)
2013-05-04 05:39:29.983+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.n.s.StoreFactory]: /usr/local/neo4j-enterprise-2.0.0/data/graph.db/neostore non clean shutdown detected
2013-05-04 05:39:29.983+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.n.s.StoreFactory]: [/usr/local/neo4j-enterprise-2.0.0/data/graph.db/neostore] brickCount=0 brickSize=0b mappedMem=0b (storeSize=54b)
2013-05-04 05:39:30.023+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.t.x.XaLogicalLog]: Non clean shutdown detected on log [/usr/local/neo4j-enterprise-2.0.0/data/graph.db/nioneo_logical.log.1]. Recovery started ...
2013-05-04 05:39:30.029+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.t.x.XaLogicalLog]: [/usr/local/neo4j-enterprise-2.0.0/data/graph.db/nioneo_logical.log.1] logVersion=8 with committed tx=503
2013-05-04 05:39:30.071+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.n.s.StoreFactory]: /usr/local/neo4j-enterprise-2.0.0/data/graph.db/neostore.relationshiptypestore.db.names hit=0 miss=0 switches=0 ooe=0
2013-05-04 05:39:30.071+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.n.s.StoreFactory]: /usr/local/neo4j-enterprise-2.0.0/data/graph.db/neostore.relationshiptypestore.db hit=0 miss=0 switches=0 ooe=0
2013-05-04 05:39:30.071+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.n.s.StoreFactory]: /usr/local/neo4j-enterprise-2.0.0/data/graph.db/neostore.propertystore.db.strings hit=0 miss=0 switches=0 ooe=0
2013-05-04 05:39:30.071+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.n.s.StoreFactory]: /usr/local/neo4j-enterprise-2.0.0/data/graph.db/neostore.propertystore.db.index.keys hit=0 miss=0 switches=0 ooe=0
2013-05-04 05:39:30.071+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.n.s.StoreFactory]: /usr/local/neo4j-enterprise-2.0.0/data/graph.db/neostore.propertystore.db.index hit=0 miss=0 switches=0 ooe=0
2013-05-04 05:39:30.075+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.n.s.StoreFactory]: /usr/local/neo4j-enterprise-2.0.0/data/graph.db/neostore.propertystore.db.arrays hit=0 miss=2 switches=0 ooe=0
2013-05-04 05:39:30.080+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.n.s.StoreFactory]: /usr/local/neo4j-enterprise-2.0.0/data/graph.db/neostore.propertystore.db hit=0 miss=33 switches=0 ooe=0
2013-05-04 05:39:30.080+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.n.s.StoreFactory]: /usr/local/neo4j-enterprise-2.0.0/data/graph.db/neostore.relationshipstore.db hit=0 miss=0 switches=0 ooe=0
2013-05-04 05:39:30.080+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.n.s.StoreFactory]: /usr/local/neo4j-enterprise-2.0.0/data/graph.db/neostore.nodestore.db.labels hit=0 miss=0 switches=0 ooe=0
2013-05-04 05:39:30.081+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.n.s.StoreFactory]: /usr/local/neo4j-enterprise-2.0.0/data/graph.db/neostore.nodestore.db hit=0 miss=33 switches=0 ooe=0
2013-05-04 05:39:30.081+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.n.s.StoreFactory]: /usr/local/neo4j-enterprise-2.0.0/data/graph.db/neostore.schemastore.db hit=0 miss=1 switches=0 ooe=0
2013-05-04 05:39:30.083+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.n.s.StoreFactory]: /usr/local/neo4j-enterprise-2.0.0/data/graph.db/neostore hit=0 miss=3 switches=0 ooe=0
2013-05-04 05:39:30.084+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]: --- STOPPING diagnostics START ---
2013-05-04 05:39:30.084+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]: --- STOPPING diagnostics END ---
2013-05-04 05:39:30.085+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.EmbeddedGraphDatabase]: Startup failed: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.XaDataSourceManager@58e5f46e' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.NeoStoreXaDataSource@5b0d95cd' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.: NodeRecord[1231] not in use
enter code here
```

the /logs folder contains console.log which shows this:

```
(NeoStoreXaDataSource.java:310)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:491)
    ... 15 more
5/4/13 5:35:31 AM org.neo4j.server.CommunityBootstrapper SEVERE: Failed to start Neo Server on port [7474]
5/4/13 5:39:28 AM org.neo4j.server.CommunityBootstrapper WARNING: WARNING! You are using an unsupported Java runtime. Please use Oracle(R) Java(TM) Runtime Environment 7.
5/4/13 5:39:28 AM org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer INFO: Setting startup timeout to: 120000ms based on -1
Detected incorrectly shut down database, performing recovery..
05:39:29.132 [main] WARN  o.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase - WARNING! You are using an unsupported Java runtime. Please use Oracle(R) Java(TM) Runtime Environment 7.
5/4/13 5:39:30 AM org.neo4j.server.CommunityBootstrapper SEVERE: 
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.XaDataSourceManager@58e5f46e' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
    at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.run(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:314)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase.<init>(EmbeddedGraphDatabase.java:106)
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory$1.newDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:89)
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseBuilder.newGraphDatabase(GraphDatabaseBuilder.java:205)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.recovery.StoreRecoverer.recover(StoreRecoverer.java:115)
    at org.neo4j.server.preflight.PerformRecoveryIfNecessary.run(PerformRecoveryIfNecessary.java:59)
    at org.neo4j.server.preflight.PreFlightTasks.run(PreFlightTasks.java:70)
    at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.runPreflightTasks(AbstractNeoServer.java:286)
    at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:129)
    at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.start(Bootstrapper.java:86)
    at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.main(Bootstrapper.java:49)
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.XaDataSourceManager@58e5f46e' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:497)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:104)
aused by: org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.InvalidRecordException
    ... 10 more
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.NeoStoreXaDataSource@5b0d95cd' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:497)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:104)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.XaDataSourceManager.start(XaDataSourceManager.java:128)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:491)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.InvalidRecordException: NodeRecord[1231] not in use

    at org.d incorrectly shut down database, performing recovery..
05:39:29.132 [main] WARN  o.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase - WARNING! You are using an unsupported Java runtime. Please use Oracle(R) Java(TM) Runtime Environment 7.
5/4/13 5:39:30 AM org.neo4j.server.CommunityBootstrapper SEVERE:
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.XaDataSourceManager@58e5f46e' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
        at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.run(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:314)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase.<init>(EmbeddedGraphDatabase.java:106)
        at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory$1.newDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:89)
        at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseBuilder.newGraphDatabase(GraphDatabaseBuilder.java:205)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.recovery.StoreRecoverer.recover(StoreRecoverer.java:115)
        at org.neo4j.server.preflight.PerformRecoveryIfNecessary.run(PerformRecoveryIfNecessary.java:59)
        at org.neo4j.server.preflight.PreFlightTasks.run(PreFlightTasks.java:70)
        at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.runPreflightTasks(AbstractNeoServer.java:286)
        at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:129)
        at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.start(Bootstrapper.java:86)
        at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.main(Bootstrapper.java:49)
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.XaDataSourceManager@58e5f46e' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:497)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:104)
aused by: org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.InvalidRecordException
        ... 10 more
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.NeoStoreXaDataSource@5b0d95cd' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:497)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:104)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.XaDataSourceManager.start(XaDataSourceManager.java:128)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:491)
        ... 12 more
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.InvalidRecordException: NodeRecord[1231] not in use
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.NodeStore.getRecord(NodeStore.java:239)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.NodeStore.getRecord(NodeStore.java:112)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.WriteTransaction.gatherUpdatesFromPropertyCommands(WriteTransaction.java:692)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.WriteTransaction.convertIntoLogicalPropertyUpdates(WriteTransaction.java:669)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.WriteTransaction.applyCommit(WriteTransaction.java:619)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.WriteTransaction.doCommit(WriteTransaction.java:561)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.xaframework.XaTransaction.commit(XaTransaction.java:321)
eo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.NodeStore.getRecord(NodeStore.java:112)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.WriteTransaction.gatherUpdatesFromPropertyCommands(WriteTransaction.java:692)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.WriteTransaction.convertIntoLogicalPropertyUpdates(WriteTransaction.java:669)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.WriteTransaction.applyCommit(WriteTransaction.java:619)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.WriteTransaction.doCommit(WriteTransaction.java:561)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.xaframework.XaTransaction.commit(XaTransaction.java:321)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.xaframework.XaResourceManager.injectTwoPhaseCommit(XaResourceManager.java:407)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.xaframework.XaLogicalLog.applyTwoPhaseCommitEntry(XaLogicalLog.java:562)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.xaframework.XaLogicalLog.applyEntry(XaLogicalLog.java:437)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.xaframework.XaLogicalLog.doInternalRecovery(XaLogicalLog.java:771)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.xaframework.XaLogicalLog.open(XaLogicalLog.java:206)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.xaframework.XaLogicalLog.open(XaLogicalLog.java:161)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.xaframework.XaContainer.openLogicalLog(XaContainer.java:64)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.NeoStoreXaDataSource.start(NeoStoreXaDataSource.java:310)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:491)
    ... 15 more
5/4/13 5:39:30 AM org.neo4j.server.CommunityBootstrapper SEVERE: Failed to start Neo Server on port [7474]
```

I'm not a JAVA programmer so I do not know how to debug this issue. I mainly use node-neo4j (node.js) to talk to my neo4j server.

Please help thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this post in the Neo4j google group.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/neo4j/3BVM4kmso5c

While it may work for a while on Java 6, eventually you are going to encounter some bugs due to wrong JDK versions. Update to Java 7 and the problem should disappear.

If it doesn't, please also make sure you are not running OpenJDK but Oracle JDK.

Answer (score 0):

The exception says:

> You are using an unsupported Java runtime. Please use Oracle(R)
>   Java(TM) Runtime Environment 7.

You are probably running java version 5 or 6. You can download Java SE 7 from [the oracle website](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).

Comment: that cannot be it. because it worked fine while i was using java 5 / 6.

Comment: Which version of Neo4j Server worked fine? I guess version 2.0 needs java 7 in order to run

Comment: as in i was using neo 2.0 when it was working fine. it just suddenly stopped working. I am guessing it has something to do with that node[1231], as reflected in the error log.